# Using IF after Else in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I am a beginner in python programming. I have a small doubt that while performing some conditional expression using "if-elif-else" block, if i am using "if" after "else" would the code under "if" run or not. I know its a bad practice, but i have to integrate a pre-written code with my application. for example:

```
jk=10

if(jk>5):
    print("hello")

elif(jk<20):
    print("not")

else:
    print("gone")

if(jk==10):
    print("home")
```

When i type the above snippet in interpreter it gives me the below error:

```
... if(jk==10):

File "<stdin>", line 5

    if(jk==10):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However when i write this in a script and run it through command line it runs perfectly without any error. Can somebody point out what i am missing here.

Comment: just so you know, your 'else' is not reachable since if jk is not > 5 it must be < 20.

Comment: the first `if`, `elif`, `else` statements are all one block. Then you start a new block with your next `if` statement, it will be evaluated regardless of the previous `if-elif-else` block.

Answer (score 8):

The `...` says that you are still within the code block for the `else` and python doesn't expect the dedent for the next `if`. Try hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> one more time for the `...` to turn back into a `>>>` and your code will work!